# Stop training MLPRegressor (solver=lbfgs) only after max_iter and not because of "tol"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am training a model using `MLPRegressor` using solver `lbfgs`. I have changed the `max_iter` parameter to 500, from the default 200. I want to force the training to continue till 500 iterations and not stop when loss is not improving by at least `tol`.

I have already tried setting tol to 0.0 and then went on to set it negative (e.g. -10)

```
mymodel = mlpr(hidden_layer_sizes=(3,), activation = 'tanh', solver = 
'lbfgs',max_iter=500, tol=0.0, verbose=True)
for i in range(99):
    mymodel = mymodel.fit(xtrain,ytrain)
    print("The number of iterations ran was: ",mymodel.n_iter_)
```

This is what I got:

```
The number of iterations ran was:  56
The number of iterations ran was:  162
The number of iterations ran was:  154 
The number of iterations ran was:  169
The number of iterations ran was:  127
The number of iterations ran was:  40
The number of iterations ran was:  501
The number of iterations ran was:  501
The number of iterations ran was:  502
The number of iterations ran was:  198
```

I expected 500 iterations every time. (Not even 501 or 502 as they are more than 500 which I specified in `max_iter`)

Comment: Try setting the `verbose` param to higher than 3 to check if `'tol'` is the main reason as you are saying. If thats so, set `n_iter_no_change` equal to `n_iter`

Answer (score 1):

The `tol` parameter specifies the tolerance for the optimization. If the loss or score not improving with at least `tol`, the training considered finished as convergence reached. Try to set the `tol` parameter to `None`, as it indicates `-infinity`, so the training won't stop until `max_iter` is reached.

```
mymodel = mlpr(hidden_layer_sizes=(3,), activation = 'tanh', solver = 
'lbfgs',max_iter=500, tol=None, verbose=True)
```

Comment: This gives an error when I run ``mymodel = mymodel.fit(xtrain,ytrain)``. Try running it on your system.

Comment: Is there any other way to write ``-infinity`` ?